# Show md-dialog on a div not on whole body

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to apply md-dialog only on a div not on the whole body , so that I can use textbox inside the header div when the md-dialog is opened.

Example : HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="first_div">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="second_div">
      <md-content>
        <md-button ng-click="showDialog($event)">Launch Dialog</md-button>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller :

```
 function showDialog($event) {
    var parentEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('md-content'));
    alert = $mdDialog.alert({
      parent: parentEl,
      targetEvent: parentEl,
      template:
        '<md-dialog aria-label="Sample Dialog">' +
        '  <md-content>'+
        '    </md-list>'+
        '  </md-content>' +
        '  <div class="md-actions">' +
        '    <md-button ng-click="ctrl.closeDialog()">' +
        '      Close Greeting' +
        '    </md-button>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</md-dialog>',
        locals: {
          closeDialog: $scope.closeDialog
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: 'DialogController'
    });
```

From the above example i want to make first_div independent of md-dialog.
only second_div should show the dialog.
So that when dialog is shown to user , user should be able to enter details in the first div.

Check CodePen for more info
[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/mJjqmK)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To position a dialog above a particular div, you must provide the parent and the targetEvent :

```
$scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#second_div')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('This is an alert title')
        .content('You can specify some description text in here.')
        .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
        .ok('Got it!')
        .targetEvent(ev)
    );
};
```

After that, to make your input available, you must apply "z-index" to the div containing your input.

CSS

```
#first_div{
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: So you are actually saying me to use Div instead of md-dialog ?? If you Have example that would be great

Comment: they example although working seems to use md-content for parent, which is not what you saying right?

var parentEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('md-content'));